# Why votes on some answers don't increase reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

For some answers the reputation doesn't seem to be counted correctly. Even when the answer get a lot of upvotes it doesn't affect the reputation in any way.

Here is an example: In [my account on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65499/rsp) I have [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif/323530#323530) with 28 points for which I've already got [5 Badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65499/rsp?tab=badges) but [my reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65499/rsp?tab=reputation) is still 101 (100 is just the account Association Bonus) and on [my profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65499/rsp) I see:

> You have no recent positive reputation changes

I have not noticed such a problem on any other of [my profiles](https://stackexchange.com/users/303952/rsp), only on Math.

I tried to find a solution but I haven't found any question or answer about similar problems. How can I solve this problem so the reputation is counted correctly? Is this a matter of my account configuration or is it an internal bug in Stack Exchange?

**Note on the question being a duplicate:** Thanks to the answers below I now know that votes on community wiki answers don't increase reputation - but for someone who doesn't know that and tries to find out why the reputation seems to be counted incorrectly it may not be obvious to ask a question: *What are “Community Wiki” posts?* So even though one can find the needed information in the referenced question, this one is not its duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That specific question is community wiki, which results in every answer to it being made community wiki as well. You don't receive any reputation for CW posts, so that is the reason why your still only have 101 reputation on Math.SE.

Community Wiki questions are confusing, but they're rarely used anymore in part due to that. Math is one of the exceptions, most sites don't use community wiki for questions at all.

Comment: I'll just add that math.se's CW love affair has seen a dramatic decline. Many questions which, in the past, would have been CWed are instead seeing close-votes and deletions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the first time I even saw a community wiki (and frankly I didn't even notice that it is one) so that's why I didn't know that I should search for "What is a community wiki" question to solve my problem. Since it was my only answer on Math, it seemed to me that the reputation on Math didn't work as expected, not that the question was special. It's strange that the argument that the answer can't be attributed to me alone still applies even when no one has ever edited my answer since I wrote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The point with that post is: it is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/245360). A community wiki is something you edit as a community, and can't be attributed to a single user. For that reason, you don't gain or lose any reputation from the votes on that post.

Since the question is a community wiki, all the answers are too. Nothing you can do about it. Just be proud of the useful contribution you have done and keep on contributing!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize that when an answer wasn't ever edited by anyone since I wrote it, the argument that it can't be attributed to me still applies. Now I know. Of course I'm proud and I'll keep contributing, I just thought something was not working correctly. Thanks a lot. (BTW, I accepted the other answer because it was 21 seconds earlier, I hope you don't mind.)